# CSS3: change width of submit button with class and id

Tags: html, css

I've read other threads about this, but 
no one worked in my context.

**This is what i wanted to achieve:**

[image]

As 07/08/2015, `<button>` is part of the `form` element ([link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zjkr.png)). So i've used:

```
<li><a href="cve.html">Mi Hoja de Vida - Español (html)</a>
   <div class="formbutton">
      <form action ="yo.png" method="get">
      <button id="spanish" type="submit" class="download">PDF Español</button>
      </form>  
   </div>
   <div class="formbutton">
      <form action ="yo.png" method="get">
        <button id="english" type="submit" class="download">PDF English</button>
      </form>  
    </div>
 </li>
```

Then i was trying to modify the width of the buttons: a) using the `class="download"` and b) using the `id="spanish"` and `id="english"`.

But using them separatly didn't result in what i expected.

**Using the class = "download"**

```
.download {
   width: 120px;
   height: auto;
   font-family: "Verdana";
   text-align: center;
}
```

*Result using class="donwload"*:

[image]

**In the CSS, i've also tried using the IDs:**

```
#spanish {
    display:block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}



#english {
    display:block;
    width: 120px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

*Result using IDs:*

[image]

Finally, i got it working using both, the classes and the ids.
But don't have idea of why this works. For me, it would be better using one of them (class or ids). Can any one explain me this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you ran into a specificity issue. Only `id` or only `class` probably would have worked if you had used `!important`. Because you are trying to override other CSS rules without using `!important`, your rules must be more specific than the preexisting rules.

You can read up more here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Example:

```css
div p.stuff {
  color: green;
  background: gray;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

div p#internal {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 175px;
  padding-top: 155px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><p class="stuff" id="internal">Testing<p></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the info. I've google it, and know making more progress.